# Thread vs Thread?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, thread-synchronization

Suppose that I have a process P1 with 4 threads, another process P2 with 4 threads and I have 4 cores. The cores are busy with my P1 process' threads.

Suppose that a thread with higher priority from P2 comes to the scene, what happens then? Does one of my P1 threads is replaced with the new comer, high priority, thread ?

If yes does that mean PCB of P1 is moved to the ready queue without being processes completely to enable context switch between P1 and P2? That is a huge overhead for the CPU to move the PCB of P1 to memory and copy the PCB of P2 to CPU, is not it? Or is there any other way so that not the whole PCB1 is moved back to ready queue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This does depend on the OS and its configuration

Comment: You're overthinking this from a strange angle. Note that in any OS it's unlikely all 4 threads of your process were running in any case. In fact your example **guarantees it** because: _Where do you think the kernel thread was running when it launched P2?_ Bear in mind that you probably have at least hundreds of threads from tens of processes active on most systems.